# Format code Php Eclipse Neon (4.6.0)

Tags: php, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Neon (4.6.0). when i try to format code Ctr+Shift+F the code is very difficultly to read.
after formating code like image two .I want code like image one. Can you help me ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open your Eclipse configuration dialog as below, select Java=>Code Style=>Formatter, then click edit the Active profile, you will see the dialog on the right side, you can change it here as you like.
[image]

Comment: Hello @Bobgao, I'm using eclipse PHP not java.